# can't call function inside <script> ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

A simple example from w3school:

```
  <form>
        Select a fruit:
        <select id="mySelect" size="4">
          <option>Apple</option>
          <option>Pear</option>
          <option>Banana</option>
          <option>Orange</option>
        </select>
</form>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
   function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect")   <---ERROR on var "Expression expected.ts(1109)"
    x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
   }                                               <---ERROR on }"Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?ts(1381)"

  </script>

  <button onclick={myFunction()}>Remove selected fruit</button>
```

but when i try to implement it I get the errors mentioned above, everything inside the script-tag is also white unless i put it inside curly brackets. I reckon this means the code doesn't complie?

I have tried installing earlier versions of typeScript but with no success.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would take a look at [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) before you go any further because it has a very specific approach to how it updates the DOM (through state).

Comment: Why would you put a script tag in a React component? And why would you get an element by an ID? Are you sure you are using React? Except for the `{myFunction()}` part this does look like simple JavaScript, no react. In React it would also be `onClick`, not `onclick`.